# Guias de indentación de bloque (if, while, try, metodo) en eclipse

Tags: eclipse

existe alguna forma de activar las guias de indentación (lineas verticales), como por ejemplo las usa VSCode, para distinguir donde inicia y termina un if, while etc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Motivo de [cierre](/help/closed-questions): _La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías u otros recursos externos_. Lee [ask].

Comment: a lo que te refieres es el foldin de bloques de codigo ... al mismo tiempo te permite ver donde inicia los if/else, while etc... ya te dejo una respuesta.

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 1):

La ultima vez que lo use (2016) esto se configuraba en:

```
Window -> 
Preferences -> 
[Lenguage] -> 
Editor -> 
Folding -> Enable folding of preprocessor branches (#if/#else)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[haca te dejo una guia en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947590/17161735) por si la ocupas.

Aparte de esta forma nativa tambien existen alternativas/pluggin que logran este cometido:

[Coffee-Bytes](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding),[EditBox](http://editbox.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: gracias por el dato, no se por que en spring tools, no aparece y los plugins, editbox, tampoco me funciono